# If $p$ and $q$ are projections how can I prove that $\|p(1-q)(x)\|\le \|q(1-q)(x)\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $p,q$ be orthogonal projection operators in a Hilbert space.

Does the following equation hold?

$$ \langle p(1-q)x,p(1-q)x\rangle = \langle p(1-q)x,x\rangle$$

It's clear to me that $ \langle p(1-q)x,p(1-q)x\rangle = \langle p(1-q)x,(1-q)x\rangle$ but it's not clear if I can go from $\langle (1-q)^\ast p(1-q)x,x\rangle$ to $\langle p(1-q)x,x\rangle$.

**Edit**

Is the image of $1-q$ invariant with respect to $p$? That is, is it true that

$$ p(\mathrm{im}(1-q))\subseteq \mathrm{im}(1-q)$$

I think the answer is yes because I can see that it's true in finite dimension. It's not 100% clear to me how to prove it in infinite dimension.

If it was indeed true and $\mathrm{im}(1-q)$ was an invariant space then $p(1-q)p=(1-q)p$ would hold.

**Edit 2**

What I wrote in the previous edit appears to be wrong: applying an orthogonal projection $p$ to the image of an orthogonal projection $q$ is not necessarily again in the image of $q$.

**Edit 3**

> If neither of this works: is there another way to derive
>
> $$ \|p(1-q)(x)\|\le \|q(1-q)(x)\|$$
>
> given $\forall x \in H: \|p(x)\|\le \|q(x)\|$?

Comment: Edit 3 is unlikely since q=q^2.

Comment: @Did I don't understand your comment: this is a step in a proof in Murphy's book (page 50).

Comment: Let me repeat: if q is a projection then q=q^2 hence q(1-q)(x)=0 for every x. **Hence**, either you miscopied the assertion from Murphy, or there is a problem in Murphy.

Comment: @Did The assumption is that for all $x\in H$ we have $\|p(x)\|\le\|q(x)\|$. In particular this holds for $x' = (1-q)(x)$ hence $$ \|p(1-q)(x)\|\le \|q(1-q)(x)\|$$

Hence neither did I miscopy from the book nor is it a mistake in the book.

Comment: Yeah, and Murphy readily deduces from this that $p=pq$ hence my remark that this implies the LHS is zero was spot-on. All in all, the reactions to your question on this page (and the fact that everything in it until Edit 3 is wrong while Edit 3 is trivially true *using the proper hypothesis*) could lead you to realize that the way you asked it is squarely misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a counter-example to the claim: let $H = \mathbb{R}^2$, let $p$ and $r$ be the orthogonal projections on to $y = x$ and the $x$-axis respectively. Take $q = 1 - r$. For $x = (1,-1)$, we then have $p(1-q)x = prx = p(1,0) = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ so that $$\langle p(1-q)x,p(1-q)x\rangle = \frac{1}{2}$$ but $\langle p(1-q)x,x\rangle = 0$.

Comment: Somethnig must be wrong since this is a step in a proof in a book I am reading.